# Wait on startService before bindService

Tags: android, android-service

It is my understanding that if I want a service to run even if nothing is bounded to it, then it must first be started with startService(Intent i).

My question is WHAT IF I want to bind to the service immediately after I start it, would the following code guarantee the service is created with startService()?

Static method within the service class:

```
public static void actStart(Context ctx) {
    Intent i = new Intent(ctx, BGService.class);
    i.setAction(ACTION_START);
    ctx.startService(i);
}
```

The binding activity:

```
BGService.actionStart(getApplicationContext());    
bindService(new Intent(this, BGService.class), serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

Comment: I'm faced same problem. Have you found decision?

Comment: The bindservice actually does wait for the startservice to finish

Comment: @Paul Do you have a source?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do here, but "Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE" creates the service then binds to the service even if it hasn't been started.

Now if you want to access it immediately after binding, you can use the onServiceConnected() method of the serviceConnection:

```
 new ServiceConnection() { 
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                IBinder service) {
            //put your code here...
        } ...
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to Bugdayci's answer, a complete example is as follows:

```
       ServiceConnection myConnection = new ServiceConnection() { 
            @Override
            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                    IBinder service) {
                    ... your code that needs to execute on service connection       

            }


    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        ... your code that needs to execute on service disconnection

    } 
        };

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, TheServiceClassName.class);
        bindService(intent, myConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

...

Without the bindService at the end, the onServiceConnected() code will not execute.